# Magick.NET to read raw and write lossless JPEG

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick, magick.net

I am stumped. How do I read a grayscale 8bit raw image and convert to lossless JPEG? This the code I have to read the raw image, but it is failing with a runtime exception of `ImageMagick.MagickMissingDelegateErrorException`

```
MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
settings.Width = 1000;
settings.Height = 800;
MagickImage image = new MagickImage("c:/users/rfonseka/desktop/image.raw", settings);
```

I am not sure how to convert it to JPEG2000 lossless format. I want to convert it in memory so I can output the bytes out to HTTP.

Comment: Just a guess; settings has a delegate you are supposed to set? Or that method isn't fully implemented?

Comment: Why not use `PNG` if you want lossless?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the executable dcraw.exe into the directory that contains the Magick.NET dll when you want to read raw files. The zip file ImageMagick-7.X.X-X-Q16-x86-windows.zip that you can download from https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows contains this file.

If you are using the `AnyCPU` version of Magick.NET you will need to configure the cache directory and place `dcraw.exe` file in that directory.

```
MagickAnyCPU.CacheDirectory = @"C:\MyProgram\MyTempDir";
```

If you don't want to do this you will need to add the folder that contains the executable to your `%PATH%`.